# Mono 3.2.3 library issues

Tags: c#, .net, dll, mono

I just installed mono 3.2.3 through Git using the master repository.  I am using nginx 1.4 with fastcgi-server4.  Right now my MVC4 app with .NET4.5 is not working.  It gives me a 400 with:

```
System.ArgumentException
Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds

Description: HTTP 400.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.
Exception stack trace:
  at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) Mono.WebServer.FastCgi.Responder:SendOutput (byte[],int)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.WebServer.FastCgi.Responder:SendOutput (byte[],int)
  at Mono.WebServer.FastCgi.WorkerRequest.SendResponseFromMemory (System.Byte[] data, Int32 length) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpRuntime.FinishWithException (System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr, System.Web.HttpException e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpRuntime.Process (System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest req) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpRuntime.RealProcessRequest (System.Object o) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.MonoWorkerRequest.ProcessRequest () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

And many of these:

```
Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Transactions/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll.so:
/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Transactions/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Messaging/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Messaging.dll.so: 
/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Messaging/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Messaging.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
```

I would really appreciate any help to solve this problem and get mono MVC 4.5 running.

Br.

Umar

Comment: AFAIK those are just warnings, is your process really aborting?

Comment: My app is not wurnning, due to this its throwing me exaption

Comment: how do you know it is not running? what error do you get in the web frontend when you try to access it? And why did you add the "C++" tag to this question?

Comment: how do you know it is not running? what error do you get in the web frontend when you try to access it?